# How to send the data over broadcast address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am trying to play around with networks. I can see the following information of my pc.

```
# ifconfig
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:CA:3A:89:EE:F1  
          inet addr:136.170.195.17  Bcast:136.170.195.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baca:3aff:fe89:eef1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2451527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:465326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:348889561 (332.7 MiB)  TX bytes:308284135 (294.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:186285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:186285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:44085804 (42.0 MiB)  TX bytes:44085804 (42.0 MiB)

p3p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CC:B2:55:BA:B6:A4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Now, I want to broadcast a data over network. So, that I can check on the other pc's whether they received my message or not? How can I do so? How can I experiment by sending data over broadcast address? What is the utility to send data over broadcast address? This is actually to clear my fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/, both for sending and receiving. Look at the examples page for inspiration ( http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES ):

> socat -
>   UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.255.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,ip-add-membership=224.255.0.1:eth0
>   transfers data from stdin to the specified multicast address using
>   UDP. Both local and remote ports are 6666. Tells the interface eth0 to
>   also accept multicast packets of the given group. Multiple hosts on
>   the local network can run this command, so all data sent by any of the
>   hosts will be received by all the other ones. Note that there are many
>   possible reasons for failure, including IP-filters, routing issues,
>   wrong interface selection by the operating system, bridges, or a badly
>   configured switch.

Comment: How about netstat? How can I do so with netstat?

Comment: netstat is for showing the stats of the network, hence the name. it's not for moving data. did you mean "netcat"?

Comment: Does netcat broadcast the data?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc